# IE 8 background image issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a not so unusuall problem but either my google skills suck or I don't know how to ask and find solutions to my problem.

I am using bootstrap3 to build my website which looks fine on IE 8 except for a banner part.

The outer .row div is 100% with a background image covering the full with. Inside the div, I have a .container div has centered content leaving some space on both ends.

In all browsers except IE8, this design works fine but on IE, the background image only goes as far as the .container leaving white space on both edges.

Here is my css

```
.heading

{ 
 background: url(../images/inner-heading-bg.png) no-repeat scroll;
background-position:center;  
background-size: cover; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
min-width: 50px;
min-width: 100%;

}
```

Please see attached image for IE [image: IE8 screenshot]

Comment: That's because IE8 doesn't support `background-size`http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Comment: I actually have the lines below at the bottom which is supposed to make it support without much success:

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/inner-heading-bg.png', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/inner-heading-bg.png', sizingMethod='scale')";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support background-size: cover; by itself, it needs a little push in the back.
You can use a polyfill like: https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill to get it working in IE8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no luck with this solution :-(

Comment: This actually got to work, I specified wrong path for the HTC, i think was tired last afternoon to be keen enough to notice mistake. Thanks alot